# MSP error: the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I first generate crypto materials using `cryptogen` and then start, for example, `org1` CA server like so:

```
fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile $(ls crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1/ca/*.pem) --ca.keyfile $(ls crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1/ca/*_sk) -d -b admin:adminpw --port 7054
```

From NodeJS SDK I can enroll admin and register (and enroll) new users. But when I try to access Fabric network with these new user credentials or even admin credentials, I get the below error on SDK console:

```
root@peer0:/var/hyperledger/api# ts-node src/invoke.ts 
Wallet path: /var/hyperledger/api/wallet
2019-10-08T13:32:17.819Z - warn: [DiscoveryEndorsementHandler]: _build_endorse_group_member >> G0:0 - endorsement failed - Error: 2 UNKNOWN: access denied: channel [private-channel] creator org [Org1MSP]
2019-10-08T13:32:17.826Z - warn: [DiscoveryEndorsementHandler]: _build_endorse_group_member >> G0:0 - endorsement failed - Error: 2 UNKNOWN: access denied: channel [private-channel] creator org [Org1MSP]
2019-10-08T13:32:17.833Z - warn: [DiscoveryEndorsementHandler]: _build_endorse_group_member >> G1:0 - endorsement failed - Error: 2 UNKNOWN: access denied: channel [private-channel] creator org [Org1MSP]
2019-10-08T13:32:17.841Z - warn: [DiscoveryEndorsementHandler]: _build_endorse_group_member >> G1:0 - endorsement failed - Error: 2 UNKNOWN: access denied: channel [private-channel] creator org [Org1MSP]
Failed to submit transaction: Error: Endorsement has failed
```

`peer` log says:

```
MSP error: the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority.
```

I'm using exactly the same credentials in peer CLI container and SDK. I can do all chaincode operations from CLI, but why peers don't accept connection from SDK? 
Does `FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME` has anything to do with it? Does `cryptogen` also create a `FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME` for the CA server? If so, are peer credentials associated with the CA name? In NodeJS SDK, I tried `caName=ca-org1` as well as `caName=ca.org1`, but still getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this (or something very simalar) and managed to resolve it. The issue for me was incorrect paths to my .pem and private key files in the `fabric-ca-server start` command.

If the paths are incorrect, when the CA container starts it will be unable to locate your files (generated by `cryptogen`) so will generate its own.

The enroll and register scripts generate identities based on your `cryptogen` material, which is correct, but they're not the certs your CA has decided to generate for you.

To check if this is what's happening, have a look at the CA logs:

`docker logs <your ca container>`

Near the top where the server starts up, look for messages referring to missing keys, or messages about generating files.

Hope that helps.